# Rails: how use JQueryUI

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I have rails 3.2.1 and to test JQuery UI, i want display a DatePicker. So, in the "new.hmtl.erb" page i've put the following tag:

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>
```

In the project.js.coffee (the "new" view page is rendered by the project controller) i've write:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
```

Why the DatePicker doensn't show up?

In the source code of new page i've:

```
<script src="/assets/projects.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

that contains:

```
(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker();
 }).call(this);
```

I must include some gems? In the application.js i have:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the code that will initialize your UI object goes to the page in you case `new.html.erb`. You add it on bottom as:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
</script>
```

This means when page is loaded it will initialize your input object. In case you need this part of the code to be available trough many pages you add this code in `application.html.erb` layout. More about layouts you can reads on Rails Guide pages.

**EDIT**

For educational purposes here are additional comments:
If you want to put code in `application.js` you can do following:

```
function setDatePicker() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
}
```

and then do

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    setDatePicker();
  });
</script>
```

If you want code that will execute when `application.js` is loaded you just put it there without wrapping it in function (not advised). It will execute when application.js is loaded but it will not work since it can trigger (and probably will) before you DOM is loaded. So always use jquery's `.ready`.

Comment: Thx... if i put that code inside the new.html.erb works. But, instead, can i put it in application.js?

Comment: Well it does not make sense to keep it in application.js. If you create page `show.html.erb` you will not have datapicker input on the page and it will break. What you can do is create function `setDatePicker()` in `application.js` and call it from `.ready`. Rule of the thumb in my experience is if this code is specific for this page (it is since you are referencing ID for HTML element on this page) than it should not go into `application.js`.

Comment: I'm agree with you...but it's only for learning how works....why if i puts the script code in application.js doesn't work? I can't put it there?